# Add the ability to have rejected "edit proposals" reviewed independantly or by vote

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

i have recently recieved a few rejections to proposed edits that i think are exactly the same "value" as other proposals with exactly the same amount and type of suggestions.

Is there a peer review process planned or being discussed or already rejected for these situations

I realize the sheer amount of edit reviews that need to be looked over are overwhelming. Is there a way to spread this burden out amoung the community or perhaps a post-review process for specific proposals that are in question?

Comment: As the edit review process is implemented Stack Exchange wide this should probably be on the mother meta unless you are claiming that there is something so special about edit reviews on physics that it justifies a site specific handling (be aware that the team is rarely on board for such claims).

Comment: I Would approve the move and any edits to tags and the organization of the question if you are so inclined.

Comment: @dmckee: I am partial to physics because everything is special even relativity!  In a purely analytical way, no nothing special about this specific site.  Specifically, Is there a review of another empowered members decision on a edit suggestion.  Do these questions need to be brought up on a question specific basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to spread this burden out among the community or perhaps a post-review process for specific proposals that are in question?

Reviewing edits is [a power enabled for all users with at least 2000 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit). Currently that is <s>15</s> more than 160 users on Physics.SE.

Plus any team members who drop by and decide to put in a little work on our site in particular.